# Swiftlint unused_import rule does not work

Tags: swift, linter, swiftlint

I am using swiftlint for my project with SPM

I want to use `unused_imports` rule like this:

```
...
analyzer_rules:
  - unused_import
...
```

But it does not find any violations, even thought they are in the project

I have also tried turn it on in the `opt-in-rules` section

Do you have any ideas, why this could happened?

I am running `swiftlint lint --autocorrect`

Comment: This isn’t something swiftlint can handle in normal mode, you need to run `swiftlint analyze`, please read the documentation for more detailed information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution

You need to build your project (or workspace) using `xcodebuild` tool and save the build logs

Then you may use it to run `swiftLint analyze`

I created this makefile script to do so:

```
# Run swiftlint analyze
lint-analyze:
make clean
    xcodebuild \
    -project <YOUR_PROJECT>.xcodeproj \
    -scheme <YOUR_SCHEME> \
    -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 13 Pro Max,OS=15.5' \
    > xcodebuild.log 
    swiftlint analyze --fix --compiler-log-path xcodebuild.log --quiet
    swiftlint lint --fix --format --quiet
```